# How do I get the projection matrix of a camera after stereo rectification?

Tags: opencv

I'm able to get the projection matrix out of a monocular setup after using calibrateCamera.

[This stackoverflow answer explains how.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101747/how-can-i-get-the-camera-projection-matrix-out-of-calibratecamera-return-value)

Now, I follow the stereo calibration sample and I would like to do the same for both cameras after I do stereo rectification ([openCV - stereo rectify](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify)). The method gives me Q, R1, R2, P1 and P2 matrices.

```
void stereoRectify(InputArray cameraMatrix1, InputArray distCoeffs1, InputArray cameraMatrix2, InputArray distCoeffs2, Size imageSize, InputArray R, InputArray T, OutputArray R1, OutputArray R2, OutputArray P1, OutputArray P2, OutputArray Q, int flags=CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, double alpha=-1, Size newImageSize=Size(), Rect* validPixROI1=0, Rect* validPixROI2=0 )
```

I assume I have to combine them somehow, but I don't understand how to relate these output matrices to intrinsics and extrinsics of a camera.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Let's assume my cameras don't have distortion. I understand I can get remap the images using initUndistorRectifyMap and remap. But, I'm just interested in writing some of my own code by using the projection matrix, i.e. if it's just a single camera calibration, I get the camera matrix C, and the rotation and translation vector, I combine them to the projection matrix by C * [R |t]. I'd like to do the same but for the rectified camera position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is somewhat obvious, although it wasn't so at the time. The projection matrices I'm looking for was P1 and P2. I was wondering how to construct them with distortion parameters. Actually, this is not necessary, because the whole remap process undistorts the images, so that we can straight away make use P1 and P2 as the projection. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

What kind of projection matrix do you need?

The `stereoRectify` only computes the the rotation matrices for each camera that transforms both image plane onto a common image plane. This makes all the epipolar lines parallel and thus you have the find point correspondences per raster lines. I.e. you have a 2D point `X1 = (x1, y1)` on the image plane of camera #1 then the corresponding point on camera #2 will be located over the raster line with the same `y1` component. So the search is simplified to one dimension.

If you are interested in computing the joint undistortion and rectification transformation the you should use the output of `stereoRectify` as the input of [`initUndistortRectifyMap`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#initundistortrectifymap) and then `remap` to apply the projection. I.e.:

```
stereoRectify( M1, D1, M2, D2, img_size, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, -1, img_size, &roi1, &roi2 );

Mat map11, map12, map21, map22;
initUndistortRectifyMap(M1, D1, R1, P1, img_size, CV_16SC2, map11, map12);
initUndistortRectifyMap(M2, D2, R2, P2, img_size, CV_16SC2, map21, map22);

Mat img1r, img2r;
remap(img1, img1r, map11, map12, INTER_LINEAR);
remap(img2, img2r, map21, map22, INTER_LINEAR);
```

---

**Update #1:**

Say you have a point in the world coordinate system: `P_W`. It can be transformed into the camera coordinate system by multiplying it with the extrinsic parameters, i.e. `P_C = R*P_W + T` or `P_C = [R|T] * P_W`.

After the rectification you will have two matrices for each cameras:

- A rotation matrix for each camera (`R1`, `R2`) that makes both camera image planes the same plane, and
- A projection matrix in the new (rectified) coordinate system for each camera (`P1`, `P2`), as you can see, the first three columns of `P1` and `P2` will effectively be the new rectified camera matrices.

The transformation of points into the rectified camera coordinate system can be done by a simple matrix multiplication: `P_R = R1*P_C`.
And the transformation into the rectified image plane is similar as above: `p_R = P1*R1*P_C`

Comment: I added an edit. I'm looking for a projection matrix for each of the cameras. I have gone through this sample. I'm wondering whether I just need to multiply the projection matrices before rectification by the rectification matrix (R1 or R2 depending on the camera), this way to get the projection matrix (which is the combined camera and external matrices).

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I wanted. I'm testing some code right now, with your answer. I will be back with the results. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't notice that you started transforming with a point in the world. I'd like to get the matrix, that will transform the world point into the rectified image plane as a single 3 x 4 matrix, similar to the projection matrix I talk about earlier. I believe going in the reverse direction of your answer would give me this, but it would be great to have the matrix computation in the answer as that's what was requested.

Comment: Also, if P_R is 3 x 1 and P1 is 3 x 4, should I transform P_R into a 4 x 1 matrix by setting, P_R.at<double>(3, 0) = 1.0... ?